# What would make a function reflexive, transitive, and/or symmetric?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, relations

A binary relation $R$ is a subset of the Cartesian product between two sets $X$ and $Y$, containing a set of ordered pairs $\{(x,y) : x \in X, y \in Y\}$. $R$ is a function if each element of $X$ is the first component of at most one ordered pair, injective if each element of $Y$ is the second component of at most one ordered pair, surjective if each element of $Y$ is the second component of at least one ordered pair, and bijective if it is both injective and surjective. Surjectivity and injectivity are independent of functionality; eg, a relation can be surjective and/or injective without being a function, as they are not composite relation types like bijections and equivalence relations.

So, can a function also be symmetric, transitive, total and/or reflexive? Would the definitions then, for a function $f : X \rightarrow Y$, be:

- Symmetric: $f(x) = y \rightarrow f(y) = x$
- Transitive: $f(x) = y, f(y) = z \rightarrow f(x) = z$
- Total: $f(x) = y \lor f(y) = x$
- Reflexive: $f(x) = x$

Intuitively, the identity function $f(x) = x$ is all of these, $f(x) = -x$ is total and symmetric, no injection is transitive, no function is transitive if $x \neq y \neq z$, and every surjective function is total, but are there others? Is there an arithmetic function between numbers that's symmetric, or that's transitive, or both? If so, what is it (or are they) and if not, why not?

Comment: It is important to take care of what $X$ and $Y$ are. For example if $X \ne Y$ then your first guess at Symmetry doesn't make sense since then $f$ cannot be applied to $y$.

Comment: Huh? Do you mean as in if X and Y are of different domains like $Z$ to $N$? Which first guess at symmetry and why wouldn't it make sense?

Comment: @Mathemert Symmetric, reflexive, and transitive relations are usually properties of binary relations on a single set $X$.

Comment: @ShawnO'Hare Can't they be properties of binary relations in Cartesian products as I discussed in the first sentence of my post/question, as my thoughts are about their characterizing functions which can be from different domains?

Comment: @Mathemert I think you misunderstood me.  A binary relation $R$ on a single set $X$ is still a subset of $X \times X$.  How would you characterize a reflexive relation $R$ from $X$ to $Y$, for instance, when $X \neq Y$ and both are non-empty?  One attempt is to say $R$ is reflexive provided $(x, x) \in R$ for all $x \in X$ (ignoring $Y$), but then a necessary condition for reflexivity is $X \subseteq Y$ and $R \subseteq X \times X$.  Or you might say $R$ is reflexive if $(z, z) \in R$ for all $z \in X \cap Y$, but then again you're implying $R \subseteq (X \cap Y) \times (X \cap Y)$.

Comment: About this topic I have already delivered a lecture in the refresher course, conducted by the Academic Staff College, North Bengal University, West Bengal, India in January, 2014. In that lecture, many original results, established by me, were presented by me.

Answer (score 6):

I would prefer to speak about a *"functional relation"* here rather than a "function", because the latter wording implies that the only thing you're planning to do with it is to apply it to inputs, and here you're doing something quite different.

That being said, here are some comments on your observations:

> $f(x)=−x$ is total and symmetric,

In general a function whose relational representation is symmetric is known as an [involution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Involution_%28mathematics%29). Written functionally, the condition is $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x$ in the domain.

> no injection is transitive

The identity function is an injection whose relation is transitive.

> every surjective function is total

No. For example $f(x)=x+1$ is surjective $\mathbb R\to \mathbb R$, yet we have neither $f(\pi)=235$ nor $f(235)=\pi$.

If "total" is taken to imply reflexivity, the only functions whose relations are total are the empty function and the unique function $\{x\}\to \{x\}$ for a singleton set $\{x\}$.

If "total" means only that *different* elements must be related one way or the other (such that, e.g., "$<$" counts as a total order), we also get (a) constant functions when $|X|=2$, and (b) cyclic permutations of a set with 2 or 3 elements.

> no function is transitive if $x\ne y\ne z$

We don't speak about a relation being transitive for a particular triple of $(x,y,z)$. It's the *entire* relation that is either transitive or not, meaning that the property has to hold for *all* such triples.

In functional notation, "transitive" comes down to $f(f(x))=f(x)$ -- in other words, whether the function is [idempotent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotent).

---

$f(x)=|x|$ is an example of a function that is idempotent ("transitive") but not an involution ("symmetric").

$f(x)=-x$ is an involution ("symmetric") but not idempotent ("transitive").

The only function $X\to X$ that is both idempotent and an involution is the identity function.

Comment: I believe the examples you gave of total functions are actually examples of connected functions, as a total relation is reflexive, and the only reflexive function on a set is the identity map.

Comment: @Shawn: I think there are authors who explicitly exclude the case $x\mathrel R x$ from their definition of "total", such that they can speak about whether strict partial orders are total or not.

Comment: I've always heard that relaxed condition referred to as a connected relation, but I certainly believe you.

Comment: Hi Henning, thanks for the great answer and sorry for responding so late! I am a bit confused about how idempotency is related to transitivity in the set-relational sense; could you clear that up? And also as to why $f(x) = -1$ is not idempotent, as it satisfies $f(f(x)) = f(x)$ as $f(x) = -1, f(-1) = -1, f(-1) = f(x)$.

Comment: @Mathemert: Sorry, $f(x)=-1$ was a typo. It should have been $f(x)=-x$, fixed now.

Comment: Transitivity would say that whenever $f(x)=y$ and $f(y)=z$ then $f(x)=z$. In other words, whenever $f(f(x))=z$ then $f(x)=z$. In other words, $f(f(x))=f(x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Here are some ideas that can help:
For $f:\mathbb{R} \longrightarrow \mathbb{R}$ to be symmetric you need $f(f(x))=x$ (because we need if $(x,y) \in f$, then $(y,x)  \in f$. Now functions of the form $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)=-x+c$ will satisfy this condition.

Comment: Ah, I see it does, but why does $f(x)=−x+c$ satisfy the condition?

Comment: because $f(f(x))=f(-x+c)=-(-x+c)+c=x$.

Answer (score 1):

The identity function $1_X \colon X \to X$ on a set $X$ induces an equivalence relation on $X$ since it partitions $X$ into its singleton sets.

A function $f \colon X \to X$ is symmetric if and only if $f(f(x))=x$ for all $x \in X$, so $f$ must be an involution, which is to say $f^2 = 1_X$.

If $\lvert X \rvert > 2$, then $f \colon X \to X$ cannot be total.  In particular any total relation is reflexive.  If $f(x) \neq x$ for some $x \in X$, then $x$ is not related to $x$, so $f$ is not reflexive.  So the only possible total function is the identity $1_X$.   But the identity function cannot relate two distinct elements $x \neq y$.